# How to compare similar field names in different type of objects in collections in Spock?

Tags: groovy, spock, assertions

I have two collections of different types - eg. `Fruit` and `Vegetable`.

Now in spock I assert contents of those collections in one of the following ways:

```
fruits.size() == vegetables.size()
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.size(); i++) {
    assert fruits[i].name == vegetables[i].name
    assert fruits[i].active == vegetables[i].enabled
}
```

Is there any better way to compare such collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [Groovy's spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator) to extract list of values and compare those lists. Consider following example:

```
class Fruit {
    String name
    boolean active
}

class Vegetable {
    String name
    boolean enabled
}

def fruits = [new Fruit(name: 'Apple', active: false), new Fruit(name: 'Tomato', active: true)]
def vegetables = [new Vegetable(name: 'Apple', enabled: false), new Vegetable(name: 'Tomato', enabled: false)]

assert fruits.name == vegetables.name
assert fruits.active == vegetables.enabled
```

First assertion passes, because:

```
assert ['Apple', 'Tomato'] == ['Apple', 'Tomato']
```

However second assertion fails, because:

```
assert fruits.active == vegetables.enabled
       |      |      |  |          |
       |      |      |  |          [false, false]
       |      |      |  [Vegetable@5b8dfcc1, Vegetable@2f9f7dcf]
       |      |      false
       |      [false, true]
       [Fruit@747ddf94, Fruit@35e2d654]
```

In this case you don't have to compare if both lists have the same size and also order of objects matters. The only downside is that values you extract to lists have to be comparable - otherwise it will compare references to objects.

Finally, your Spock test could look like this:

```
def "comparing fruits and vegetales"() {
    when:
    def fruits = initializeFruits()
    def vegetables = initializeVegetables()

    then:
    fruits.name == vegetables.names

    and:
    fruits.active == vegetables.enabled
}
```